# Gnuplot and complex exponentials

Tags: gnuplot

Could anyone tell me how to draw complex exponentials using gnuplot. I tried to draw them using this script, but argument `i` isn't recognized.

```
set terminal epslatex color colortext size 9cm,5cm
set size 1.5,1.0
set output "eulerjeva_identiteta_1.tex"

set style line 1 linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#FF0055"
set style line 2 linetype 2 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#FF0055"
set style line 3 linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#2C397D"
set style line 4 linetype 2 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#2C397D"
set style line 5 linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#793715"
set style line 6 linetype 2 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#793715"
set style line 7 linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#b1b1b1"
set style line 8 linetype 3 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#b1b1b1"

set grid

set samples 7000

set key at graph .95, 0.4
set key samplen 2
set key spacing 0.8

f(x) = exp(i*x)
g(x) = exp(-i*x)
h(x) = exp(i*x)+exp(-i*x)

set xrange [-2*pi:2*pi]
set yrange [-1.2:1.2]

set xtics ("$0$" 0, "$\\pi$" pi, "$-\\pi$" -pi)
set ytics ("$1$" 1, "$-1$" -1)

set xlabel "$x$"

plot [-2*pi:2*pi] f(x) ls 1 title "$\\e^{ix}$", g(x) ls 3 title "$\\e^{-ix}$", h(x) ls 5 title "$\\e^{ix} + \\e^{-ix}$"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Gnuplot doesn't understand `i` as `sqrt(-1)` because the variable `i` is not assigned a value by gnuplot--it is just another variable name as far as it is concerned.  Gnuplot can understand and manipulate complex numbers using the format

```
z = {a,b}
```

which represents a complex number `z = (a + ib)` in written notation.  So, i could be defined

```
i = {0.0,1.0}
```

There is still the problem of what you would get when you then graph

```
plot exp(i*x)
```

All the points are 'undefined' because they have an imaginary component.  (Although, `h(x) = exp(i*x)+exp(-i*x)` would plot fine since it is purely real.)  The problem is that gnuplot can plot only real quantities.  You could try

```
plot real(exp(i*x)), imag(exp(i*x))
```

to visualize the components separately, or you could make a parametric plot:

```
set parametric
plot real(exp(i*t)), imag(exp(i*t))
```

Comment: I think that would be `plot imag(exp(i*x))`, since exp(i*x) = cos(x) + i*sin(x).

Comment: Note that `exp(ix)=cos(x)+i sin(x)`.